# Schedule a Job to run once a day in maestro scheduler

Tags: scheduling

I wanted to run Job on a maestro scheduler automatically every business day whenever the file is a available on a specific file share. The job needs to run once only on a given day as soon as it sees the file. in the sense I don't want Job to run forever as I don't have write access on the publishing folder.

```
SCHEDULE Server1#Jobstream1
ON RUNCYCLE RULE1 "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1"
:
 Server1#Job1
  EVERY 0060
  OPENS Server1#"\\ns-abc1\app1\abc.CSV"
END
```

Here is what I wrote,how do I add a dependency to run only once daily?

Answer (score 1):

`EVERY 0060` means that the job have to run every 60 minutes. If you want to run once a day you have to remove the `EVERY 0060`. Like this:

```
SCHEDULE Server1#Jobstream1
ON RUNCYCLE RULE1 "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1"
:
 Server1#Job1
  OPENS Server1#"\\ns-abc1\app1\abc.CSV"
END
```

To start checking only at a given time, add an `AT` dependency, on the job or on the schedule, specifying the starting time. This will also improve the system performance since the check on the file will start only at the specified time.

If the file will not come every day, consider using `UNTIL time ONUNTIL SUPPR` to suppress the job after the specified time

For more complex scenario consider also the [EDWA](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGSPN_9.4.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.4/common/src_gi/eqqg1eventdriven.htm) (available since TWS 8.4) or the new [STARTCOND](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGSPN_9.4.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.4/distr/src_ref/awsrgtrigger.htm) (introduced in 9.4 FP1)

Comment: So how should be the syntax written ?

Comment: If you need a specific definition, please clarify your scenario, do you expect the file after a given time? If the file is not present today, what do you want to do?

Comment: I would want my Job to run all 365 days but it should only run once per day, because the file can be published any day any time but since I don't have write access to archive the file from the shared path I want the Job to run once on any day and after that don't at all run the Job anymore for that particular day

Comment: OK, added the syntax just removing the EVERY

Comment: Wow is it that simple,so to understand it FREQ=DAILY means runs daily and ;INTERVAL=1 will ensure it runs once a day

Comment: That's a standard iCalendar expression, FREQ=DAILY means count the days, INTERVAL=1 means run every 1 day